# Scala/Play http authentication issue - getting user name and password from request

Tags: scala, http, authentication, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Firefox "REST Easy" plugin to test HTTP authentication in my Play application. This is how the request URL looks like in Firebug:

```
http://username:password@localhost:9001/test
```

The method in my Play controller looks like this:

```
def test = Action { implicit request =>

    request.headers.get("Authorization") match {
        case Some(header) => println(header)
        case None => {
            println("send user name and password")
            Unauthorized.withHeaders("WWW-Authenticate" -> "Basic realm=\"myrealm\"")
        }           
    }

    Ok("")

}
```

I'm getting "send user name and password" in my console and nothing else happens. What am I doing wrong and how do I get the user name and password from the request?

Comment: Have you check the headers? You read the Authorization header - not a http parameter.

Comment: @ajozwik What do you mean? I though that basic HTTP auth - user name and password - are passed in headers, is it not?

Comment: Looks like you need to choose the Authentication tab and enter a username/password there.  Like RedmarKerkhoff's curl answer, that should be converted to the proper basic authorization header.  If it is an issue with the plugin, I can verify that the FF plugin RESTClient's Basic Authorization does construct a proper header(tested against Scalatra).

Comment: LOL at the port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine, the problem is in your used browser plugin. Somehow it doesn't work with basic auth because if you add a println(request.headers) call as the first line of your action body you can see it's not in there, while if you use curl it's there!

I used the following commind with your given code:

```
curl --user name:password http://localhost:9000/test
```

and it results in:

```
Basic bmFtZTpwYXNzd29yZA==
```

So it works!

Comment: to exactly match your question the port should be 9001 BTW

Comment: as a bonus there's a complete basic auth example from the "Play for Scala" book which you can find here: https://github.com/playforscala/sample-applications/blob/master/ch08-single-page-javascript-application/authentication/app/controllers/Application.scala#L56